# Sharing of keychain values across apps with similar bundle id's

Tags: ios, keychain

I have two versions of the same app. One has the bundle id: `com.company.app` and the other has the bundle id: `com.company.app.beta`. I'm finding that a keychain value is being shared across these two apps. I have *not* set up key chain sharing.

[image]

Has anyone else seen this?

I'm using the `KeychainAccess` Cocoapod, but I'm not sure that matters. I'm using iOS 11.1.

With `KeychainAccess`, I was using:

```
Keychain(service: "com.company.app")
```

in *both* apps. So, this may be part of the cause. Still, I wouldn't expect this sharing to occur without explicitly requesting/allowing it.

Comment: Just a thought; what does Keychain Access (the macOS app) say about this keychain item, in its "Access Control" tab? Do both apps show up in there?

Comment: This is in relation to iOS.

Comment: Sorry, so it is — I totally missed that.